# Wordpress WP_Query for multiple IDs returns null

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following array:

```
array (12,15,21,32,33);
```

And then I use the following query to get the posts (of the above of IDs):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array("post__in"=>$ids_array) );       // edited

    while($the_query->have_posts())
    {
$the_query->the_post(); // added on edit, but still does not work      
the_title()."<br />";
    }
```

But I get nothing, no error and no interruption. I have checked the IDs and they are correct.

EDIT: I have put this query at the end of a module which is loaded into the footer. I don't know if it is important or not:

Comment: If $ids_array is already an array, why are you putting it into another array? Shouldn't your code just be `$the_query = new WP_Query( array("post__in"=>$ids_array) ); `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();`.

You are just checking to see if you have posts, but doing nothing further

```
$ids_array = array (12,15,21,32,33);

$the_query = new WP_Query( array('post__in'=>$ids_array) );       

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></br>
  <?php
     endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
   endif; 
  ?>
```

**EDIT**

I think the underlying problem here is not this custom query, as this custom query works. It seems from your comments that you are using another custom query on the same page.

I don't know what the code of the first query looks like, but here are some troubleshooting points you need to go and have a look at

- Most probably you did not reset the postdata on your first query. This will break your second query. [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) is extremely important when you are running custom queries with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and with [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Check that you have used `wp_reset_postdata` after your first instance of `WP_Query`. Your first query should be in the same format as the one in my answer
- You should use different variables for each instance of `WP_Query`. For example `$variable1 = new WP_Query( YOUR ARGUMENTS )` for first instance and `$variable2 = new WP_Query( YOUR ARGUMENTS )` for your second instance

Comment: it does not work. Could it be due to previous usages of WP_Query? Because when I use a direct ID with "p" instead of "post__in", it still returns noting?

Comment: See update. Added more info according to your comment